# How to join two tables with multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, database, join

I have a table where I am attempting to join two databases with the common column id. Doing the queries separately, I get what I want. putting them together and error central lol.

I want the table to have
 customer_id
 package_id
 customer_name
on one table

I tried this with outer, full, left and right joins and I get "The multi-part identifier could not be bound" and "Incorrect syntax near the keyword ''." errors.

```
SELECT 
    TABLEA.customer_id, 
    TABLEA.package_id
FROM 
    TABLEA A
OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        TABLEB.customer_name,
        TABLEB.customer_id,


    FROM
        TABLEB B
    )
ON
    A.customer_id = B.customer_id
```

I get "The multi-part identifier could not be bound" and "Incorrect syntax near the keyword ''." errors.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar. Show as much as possible that constituent subexpressions are OK.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to format your code neatly to ease readability.

```
SELECT A.customer_id, A.package_id 
FROM TABLEA A 
    OUTER JOIN (SELECT customer_name, customer_id,
                FROM TABLEB) B ON A.customer_id = B.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

- You need a table alias.
- `OUTER JOIN` doesn't (generally) mean anything.  You need `FULL`, `LEFT` or `RIGHT` before it.
- Once you declare a table alias for a table, you need to use it.

So:

```
SELECT TABLEA.customer_id, TABLEA.package_id
FROM TABLEA A LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT B.customer_name, B.customer_id,
      FROM TABLEB B
     ) B
     ON A.customer_id = B.customer_id;
```

This query is actually non-sensical, because because you are only selecting from the first table.  But it does illustrate the syntax.